# How to exclude nodes surrounding a text node?

Tags: xpath

I feel like I'm missing something basic but I can't figure it out; given this xml:

```
<p>
  <tag>good text</tag>
  <tag>this may be good </tag>
  bad text
  <tag>some other bad text</tag>
  <tag>last good text</tag>
</p>
```

I would like to select everything EXCEPT the text node (`bad text`) and the immediately following tag node. Obviously, the number of good tags and standalone text node varies, so I can't rely on their absolute positions.

I know that

```
p/text()
```

selects `bad text` and

```
//p/*
```

selects all `p` children while excluding `bad text`. But I can't figure out how to end up with only the first, second and fourth tags, in this example.

Desired output:

```
<p>
  <tag>good text</tag>
  <tag>this may be good</tag>
  <tag>last good text</tag>
</p>
```

Comment: Your description of what you want is quite unclear.  Try showing it as XML as you've done for your input XML, and also be clear on what differentiates the desired from the not desired nodes.

Comment: @kjhughes - Fair enough; I edited (and hopefully clarified) the question.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  XPath can select, not transform.  If you're ok with just those selected children of `p`, then see @Alejandro's good answer (+1).  If you require the `p` too, use XSLT.

Comment: @kjhughes - Good point! I do my best to avoid XSLT :), so I'm going to settle for Alejandro's answer indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath 1.0 expression:

```
/p/*[not(preceding-sibling::node()[1][normalize-space(self::text())='bad text'])]
```

It selects:

```
<tag>good text</tag>
<tag>this may be good or bad</tag>
<tag>last good text</tag>
```

Meaning:

> Select child elements of `p` not having as first preceding node a text node with "bad text" string as space normalized string value.

Check: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/96aa0415f3512b0a84ad1e2330e0278f